# How to get kill-buffer-hook to detach a screen session prior to kill-buffer?

Tags: hooks, kill-buffer, term

I keep many screen session running in the backgroud, which I access with `M-x eshell-command "screen -r <myscreen>"`.  Before I kill the `*screen*` buffer, I have to detach the session with `C-a d`.  It would be nice to have that integrated into `kill-buffer` via `kill-buffer-hook`, but I don't know how because the `*screen*` buffer is read-only, so `insert` doesn't work.

My non-working idea is:

```
(add-hook `term-mode-hook (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook (insert (kbd "C-a d"))))
```

What's the proper elisp command to send control-sequence inputs to a terminal via a hook?

Comment: I tried `C-a d` in a `term-mode` buffer and it is not bound to anything by default.  What Emacs function are you intending to call when you press `C-a d`?  Also, what steps -- how -- do you "kill the `*screen*` buffer"?  Finally, why does your question mix and match  using an `eshell-command` with a `term-mode` buffer -- aren't they two distinctly separate animals?

Comment: @lawlist AFAIU `eshell` employs `term` buffers to handle certain commands which it knows need a proper terminal emulator; so I think `eshell` is *mostly* irrelevant here in practice.

Comment: @lawlist `C-a d` is the key sequence to detach a `screen` session.  I use `eshell` because it can't be run from `shell` in Emacs.  True that `eshell` is mostly irrelevant here, but not knowing the solution, I thought it best to give as much detail as reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

An elisp `insert` into the terminal *buffer* does not communicate with the terminal *process* at all. `(term-send-raw-string (kbd "C-a d"))` is probably what you want to do.

Something like this?

```el
(defun my-screen-detach ()
  "Send 'C-a d' to the terminal."
  (if (derived-mode-p 'term-mode)
      (when (process-live-p (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
        (message "Sending screen detach key sequence.")
        (term-send-raw-string (kbd "C-a d")))
    (user-error "Not a `term-mode' buffer.")))

(defun my-term-exec-hook ()
  "Custom `term-exec-hook' behaviours."
  ;; If "screen" was the command being run in the terminal, then
  ;; arrange to send a 'detach' screen command if we kill the
  ;; buffer.
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    ;; (message "%S" (process-command proc))
    (if (member "/usr/bin/screen" (process-command proc))
        (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'my-screen-detach nil :local)
      (remove-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'my-screen-detach :local))))

(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'my-term-exec-hook)
```

Comment: I think *ideally* you would use a process sentinel to trigger the behaviour, rather than assuming `kill-buffer-hook` is sufficient.  That complicates things more, though (partly because processes can only have one sentinel, so you need to take more care).  nadvice.el possibly makes that relatively simple to do nowadays, though.

Comment: I am wondering, though -- does killing the screen process not implicitly cause that 'detach'?  Does it not clean up after itself in that scenario?  (I don't use screen, so I don't entirely understand the issue.)

Comment: Indeed, on Ubuntu, the detach happens cleanly when I kill the buffer, but my recollection is that on CentOS, I had some trouble re-attaching screens after killing non-detached sessions.  Regarding your solution, it *almost* works -- its just that the hook executes after the buffer is already closed, so I still get the "Buffer...has a running process" check before and a "error in process filter: Selecting deleted buffer" after.  Thank you -- this gets me on track to a solution.  I'll check out nadvice.el.

Comment: `kill-buffer-hook` runs *before* the buffer is killed. It has to. "The buffer being killed is current while the hook is running."  (Which isn't to say that there isn't an issue; just that it's not on that particular account.)  The other aspects are presumably a different question to this one.

Answer (score 0):

@phils is right about screen implicitly detaching when its buffer is killed.  This does, in fact, work cleanly under Ubuntu, CentOS and XQuartz (& probably elsewhere as well).  I found that to get the behavior I was looking for, all I really needed was to disable the exit query when screen is started.  Taking many cues from phils, here is my solution:

```
(defun my-term-exec-hook ()
  "Custom `term-exec-hook' behaviors."
  ;; suppress query on exit for screen
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (if (member "/usr/bin/screen" (process-command proc))
        (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))

(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'my-term-exec-hook)
```

many thanks!